# How do i get the angle from a joystick?

Tags: java, algorithm, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL's controller class to connect my controller and play around. I wanted to make a game where the player will face the direction the joystick is pointed and they press 'A' to fire. To rotate the player sprite i need to know the angle. I know how to get the input and the joystick inputs are in two floats, X and Y locations from -1.0 to 1.0. How would i be able to use these two numbers to find the angle that the joystick is pointing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the arc tangent function. Something like Math.Atan2(Y, X), that gives you an angle in radians. Then you multiply by 57.... to get degrees. Don't call it if both X and Y are zero.

Comment: @Steven: I forgot to mention. If what you do with that angle is get it's sine and cosine, you can just set `R = sqrt(X*X+Y*Y)`, then sine = `Y/R`, and cosine = `X/R`.